# Is there a way to scrape data from a website that is not available in the page's source?

Tags: json, xml-parsing, jsoup, html-parsing

What are the few things that I'll have to include in my code that will point me in the right direction?

[For Example this website](https://www.bestfightodds.com/)

Comment: For example what?

Comment: Yes, many ways. Generally you'll need to control a real browser, e.g. via Selenium. There are many existing resources on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your browser's debugger on Network tab and observe what are the requests when site is loading dynamic content (when you click). You'll see it's getting all the data using some API, for example: https://www.bestfightodds.com/api?f=ggd&b=3&m=16001&p=2
You can download all the data by changing parameters in this URL.
Usually that's enough but here it's more tricky as the data returned by the server is somehow encoded and not easily readable. You'd have to debug its javascript to find function which is used to decode this data before you can parse it.